# Can't get this array working, new to arrays

Tags: php

I want the array ($img_array) to increase every time it's looped, but it wont.
The length of the array is 0 when I echo it 'echo count(array);'

```
function imageSize($name, $nr, $category, $myarr){
    $path = 'ad_images/'.$category.'/'.$name.'.jpg';
    $path_thumb = 'ad_images/'.$category.'/thumbs/'.$name.'.jpg';
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($path);
    list($thumb_width, $thumb_height) = getimagesize($path_thumb);
    //$myarr = array();
    $myarr['thumb_image_' . $nr . '_width'] = $thumb_width;
    $myarr['thumb_image_' . $nr . '_height'] = $thumb_height;
    $myarr['image_' . $nr . '_width'] = $width;
    $myarr['image_' . $nr . '_height'] = $height;

    return $myarr;

}

    if ($nr_of_pics!=0){
        $image_id = end( explode( '_', $ad_id ) );
        $img_array = array();
    for ($i=1; $i<=$nr_of_pics; $i++) {
        ${'image_src' . $i} = $image_id.'_'.$i;
        imageSize(${'image_src' . $i}, $i, $category, $img_array);
        }
    }
    echo count($img_array);
    echo $img_array['image_3_width'];
```

What is wrong?

ALSO, when I echo the $img_array element as you can see, it can't find it, says undefined index...
BUT when I echo the element from INSIDE the function, it will work!

If you need more input let me know and I will update this Q.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line

```
imageSize(${'image_src' . $i}, $i, $category, $img_array);
```

to

```
$img_array = imageSize(${'image_src' . $i}, $i, $category, $img_array);
```

you are returning an array in your function but then not doing anything with it so it's gone.

Comment: Another option would be to pass the array by reference (This would be faster and require less memory).

imageSize(${'image_src' . $i}, $i, $category, &$img_array);

Answer (score 0):

`imageSize` returns an array, which i guess should be the accumulated 'image array', so set the `$img_array` to the result of the function:

```
$img_array = imageSize(${'image_src' . $i}, $i, $category, $img_array);
```